# USB 3.0 ports suddenly slow

Tags: windows-10, usb

Suddenly, after 2 years of flawless operation, the USB 3 port on my Windows 10 PC is too slow to handle the workload of both a wireless keyboard and wireless mouse. The USB 2 port still works great. What can I do to fix this?

The story:

I'm using a wireless Logitech mouse and keyboard. I bought them separately, and did not want to install the Unifying app, so they're connected using *two* of those adorable little wireless receivers.

To avoid some wireless interference from the monitor, both receivers are plugged into an [Anker USB hub](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00O0KISQE), which is plugged into one of many USB 3.0 ports on my mobo (ASRock Z97 Extreme4).

This has been working great for years. Today, I played a couple hours of Planetary Annihilation with no problem.

Then I decided to try some VR game, and Oculus prompted me to update my drivers, so I did. Suddenly, the keyboard response was really sluggish. I can push the Windows key, and the Start menu doesn't open for 10-15 seconds. Ctrl+Shift+Esc takes a few seconds to open the Task Manager. I throw up my hands and reboot. The problem remains. I haven't yet figured out it's the USB 3 port. It just seems like the computer is really sluggish, like something big is running in the background. I reboot again, and then check Task Manager, which says only 6% CPU. Keyboard still sucks.

I uninstall the Oculus application entirely, disconnect ethernet, and remove all USB connections except the USB hub and the two wireless receivers. Still sluggish, so slow I'm not actually sure it's reacting to the keyboard *at all*.

Research tells me that Windows 10 comes with a USB 3.0 driver, so I remove the Intel driver that came on my mobo CD, and then reboot. At this point I prove that it doesn't hear the keyboard at all, so I'm using just the mouse.

I finally try moving the hub to one of two USB 2.0 ports, and the problem is immediately fixed. Mouse and keyboard work perfectly.

This is not sustainable. I have too many USB devices to be accommodated by the USB 2 ports, to say nothing of the speed difference, which might not matter for most things, but a couple items (not external drives) care about the USB 3 speed.

What can I do to fix this? It seems quite clear that Oculus broke this, but I've uninstalled their app and the problem remains.

Comment: "Oculus prompted me to update my drivers" - this explains. Oculus is a division of Facebook, likely collecting a lot of "telemetry" on you in real time and improving your keystroke typing manners. Enjoy.

Comment: Have you installed Logitech's software for your keyboard and mouse _(depending on age, SetPotint or Options)_, both of which contain the Unifying software - why don't you want to use that software, as it's more convenient, doesn't introduce lag _(at least that I'm aware of)_, ensures the most up-to-date Logitech drivers are installed, and doesn't collect telemetry data unless you explicitly check the box to allow it. Just an FYI, there's no reason to plug a Logitech BT dongle into a USB 3 port - if you have free USB 2 ports, use those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did this today, you may be able to use Windows 10's System Restore function.  First, close all applications cleanly and reboot.  Look in the Windows menu for "System Restore" (it may show up as "Create a restore point").  Click "System Restore" button on the right.  Click "Show more restore points" on the bottom.  Find the most recent restore point BEFORE the problem update, then click Next.  Click Finish.  It will reboot.

That may restore the software to its previous situation.  We don't know if the Oculus update itself did it, or if another problem was merely exposed by the Oculus update.

It's worthwhile checking the ASRock driver page for the latest motherboard drivers.

Some other things worth testing : Putting the USB dongles into the front USB2 ports on the PC, which might be far enough away from monitor interference.  Trying the Unify application from Logitech (if one device has an internal storage for its dongle, store it there and go live with the other).

Comment: This worked! Although I'm perplexed as to why. Further experiments showed that the KB & mouse worked fine at *very close range* to the receivers. So... some newer software was worse at detangling multiple signals? But only when plugged in via USB 3? None of those factors should matter. Anyhow, thanks... Mr Hostage! I restored to 3 days ago, and things are back to normal. Now to experiment with upgrades.